# Can i get values from database and show it 1 by 1 every button clicked using array?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Im making a quiz app using php and i want the data including question,choice a, choice b, choice c, choice d and answer to be fetched using a set of array and display it 1 by 1 using a button. Im using this method in order to avoid duplicates in getting values.

Im not sure on what method will i try inorder to do that...

This is where i get my random array.

```
<?php
$len = 10;   // total number of numbers
$min = 1;  // minimum
$max = 10; // maximum
      $range = []; // initialize array
      foreach (range(0, $len - 1) as $i) {
      while(in_array($num = mt_rand($min, $max), $range));
      $range[] = $num;
}
session_start();
$_SESSION['range1'] = $range;
?>
```

This is my code for getting the data in my database.

```
 <?php
        session_start();
        $range = $_SESSION['range1'];
    ?>
        <?php
        print_r($range);
        $y = 0;
        $sql = "SELECT * from english where qid = $range[$y];";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $question = $row['question'];
        $choice1 = $row['choice1'];
        $choice2 = $row['choice2'];
        $choice3 = $row['choice3'];
        $choice4 = $row['choice4'];
    ?>
```

I want when every time i clicked the button. the value of the array will be incremented from $range[0] to $ranged[1] and the called data will also changed.

Comment: If you can do this in your qeury, `SELECT .....  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0` etc.  It always better to do as much as you can with the DB before coding in PHP, it will save a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip sir.. appreciate it :). Sorry im just a beginner in php hehe